# Radial Basis kernel producing the same decision boundary as a Linear kernel

Tags: artificial-intelligence, svm, kernel-functions

The following question is from the MIT 6.034 2006 Final Exam paper.

[image: Image from the MIT 6.034 2006 Final Exam paper]In answering part 6.5, I wasn't certain why the radial basis kernel would produce the same decision boundary as a linear kernel (when considering the data set shown in part 6.4). I've searched the internet for some pointers, but no dice. I was wondering if anyone familiar with SVMs would be able to shine some light on this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Comment: Please provide a full reference to the source for the copied material.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing for our guidelines on crediting material written by others.